# sqladmin vs sql-component.googleapis.com APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

What is the difference between these 2 APIs and what do they each allow you to do?

I've tried [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqladmin.googleapis.com%20vs%20sql-component.googleapis.com%20apis), [searching the GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/s/results?hl=en&q=sql-component.googleapis.com) and running some tests in the console.

The [API Library console page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/browse?q=sql) does not have very descriptive descriptions [see screenshot].

[image: API Library page showing SQL APIs]

If I leave both of those APIs disabled, I can *still* create a SQL instance! Creating a SQL instance only appears to need the Compute Engine API.

If I need to use the Python libraries to query the instance(s) for its attributes, the error message tells me that the SQL Admin API (sqladmin.googleapis.com) needs to be enabled. However, there's a twist. The API only needs to be enabled in the Project that's set in my ADC, *not* in the (other) Project that I'm actually querying.

Answer (score 0):

`Cloud SQL Admin API` aka `sqladmin.googleapis.com` is the correct api to use. You can also look at the [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest) for all the actions this API supports. You can ignore the `Cloud SQL` aka `sql-component.googleapis.com`. It is an obsolete api that does nothing.

Admin API is for administering your instances programmatically. The REST API is defined by BackupRuns, Databases, Instances, Flags, Operations, SslCerts, Tiers, and Users resources. You can check the details [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api). As you have correctly noticed this api is not required for creating Cloud SQL instances but it is required for other features like Flags, Certs BackupRuns etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kunal! Would you please add a link to where it's documented that the sql-component API is obsolete?

Comment: I dont think it is documented. You will not find any documentation for the earlier endpoint.